# JQuery Sortable Effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 9 boxes (div) on a page. I am able to move them to different positions, in a grid like fashion.

So the basic sortable functionality is fine =)

But I have a couple of questions:

What if my boxes vary in width? Which they can do, if one changes the width (1/3, 2/3 and 3/3). Can I still have one 2/3 box and a 1/3 box on the same row but different column? What about the placeholder highlight?

Why can't I move a box to an empty "ul"? I can't see the placeholder nor move a box to an empty column? This should work?

I also want my boxes to "ease" to a high-lighted placeholder when moving the box. Right now they just snap to the placeholder.

My current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("ul.connectedSortable").sortable({handle:'.kpiValueContainer'});
        $("ul.connectedSortable").sortable({connectWith:'ul'});
        $("ul.connectedSortable").sortable({placeholder:'ui-state-highlight'});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems I see in your script. You are creating a sortable 3 times. Just put all the options in 1 line of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() { 
        $("ul.connectedSortable").sortable({handle:'.kpiValueContainer', connectWith:'trysomethingelse', placeholder:'ui-state-highlight', revert: true});
    }); 
</script>
```

Second problem I see is your connectWith property. It's too broad and will also apply to your own ul.connectedSortable. I would rather use something more specific like an id or a class.

For the easing stuff take a look at the [revert](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-revert) option.

Comment: Thank you!

What about having boxes in different sizes?

Comment: You can have boxes in different sizes. It's all CSS. The placeholder is more difficult to solve. I think you need to catch an event when you start dragging, lookup which class (for the size) the current element has and then apply that size on the placeholder.

Comment: Ok.

My boxes are in 3 kolumns, <lu> element, and the box is an <li> element. Så how can I have different box and placeholder size in the same kolumn?

Can I set the <ul> width to "auto" and just adjust the <li> width? Woulnd't that cause problems?

Thanks!